# Finding the key of HashMap which holds the lowest integer value

Tags: java, iterator, hashmap

I'm creating an educational game for young students who needs to learn the most common words. On random I pick three words of the list, show them on the screen, play an audio recording of one of the three words and then the student has to pick the word that has been pronounced. I keep track of how many times they have guessed each word. In that way I can set up a criteria for when new words should be introduced to the student. When three of the words are picked I'll like to pronounce the word that the student has had least exposure to.

I have a HashMap called words, which contains the words, and a integer value of how many times the student guessed the word.

```
  HashMap<String,Integer>  words
```

It contains between 10 - 120 keys/words. I'll like to create a method, which takes three of the hash map keys as parameters, that can return the String/key having the lowest value of the keys asked for.

I have had trouple getting this to work as intended and I'd appreciate any help.

Comment: And the related code ??? I mean , what you have tried so far besides asking us?

Comment: what do you call "the lowest value of key"? what is the type of your keys?

Comment: I have seen that post and it's not useful in my case. I don't want to know what the number is, but which of the keys hold the lowest value.

Comment: Have you been able to obtain the three values from the Map so far?

Comment: Can you give an example input and output? Your question is unclear. Although any possible interpretation I can come up with should be really easy to do, even for a beginner - most of the work probably involves looking up which functions you need to call in the Java API, which begs the question - why didn't you try (or show your attempt if you did)?

Comment: So you want to find which key is associated with the lowest of three value?  I suggest you try this and see how far you get.

Comment: I have added more explanation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What about this?

```
private String getMinKey(Map<String, Integer> map, String... keys) {
    String minKey = null;
    int minValue = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
    for(String key : keys) {
        int value = map.get(key);
        if(value < minValue) {
            minValue = value;
            minKey = key;
        }
    }
    return minKey;
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Possibly the shortest solution, with Java 8:

```
private String getMinKey(Map<String, Integer> map, String... keys) {

    return map.entrySet().stream()
     .filter(p -> Arrays.asList(keys).contains(p.getKey()))
     .min(Comparator.comparingInt(Map.Entry::getValue)).get().getKey();

}
```

Answer (score 4):

First get the entry set from the map:

```
Set<Entry<String,Integer>> entries = map.entrySet();
```

Now dump that into an ArrayList so you can sort it:

```
List<Entry<String,Integer>> sortedEntries = new ArrayList<>(entries);
```

Now sort the list:

```
Collections.sort(sortedEntries, /*Define your comparitor here to compare by values */);
```

Your list now has the contents of the map sorted by value, you can access them in whatever order you like.

Answer (score 2):

This is a variation of the answer of user3309578
        static HashMap words   = new HashMap();

```
private static String getMax () {
    String minKey = null;
    int minValue = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
    for (String key : words.keySet()) {
        int value = words.get(key);
        if (value < minValue) {
            minValue = value;
            minKey = key;
        }
    }
    return minKey;
}

public static void main (String[] args) {
    words.put("a", 2);
    words.put("b", 4);
    words.put("c", 6);
    words.put("d", 8);
    words.put("e", 1);
    words.put("f", 3);
    words.put("g", 5);
    words.put("h", 7);
    System.out.println(getMax());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

i made this, it can hold multiple keys=

```
HashMap<String,Integer>hashmap_original=new HashMap<>();
        hashmap_original.put("key_1",1);
        hashmap_original.put("key_2",4);
        hashmap_original.put("key_3",1);
        hashmap_original.put("key_4",3);

        HashMap<String,Integer>hashmap_result=new HashMap<>();
        int int_minium_value = 9999; //put a maxium value that u know your code it wont pass it
        for (String String_key:hashmap_original.keySet()) {
            int int_compare_value=hashmap_original.get(String_key); //get the value

            if (int_compare_value<int_minium_value) {
                int_minium_value=int_compare_value;
                hashmap_result.clear(); //delete non min values
                hashmap_result.put(String_key,int_compare_value);
            } else if (int_compare_value==int_minium_value) {
                hashmap_result.put(String_key,int_compare_value);
            }

        }
        String result=null;//u can use a ArrayList
        for (String key_with_the_lowest_value : hashmap_result.keySet()) {
            if (result == null) {
                result = key_with_the_lowest_value;
            } else {
                result=result+","+key_with_the_lowest_value;
            }
        }
```